# Bot Channels Registration automatically assigned location "global" after migration

Tags: azure, botframework

We just migrated our bots as required by Microsoft before the deadline. I chose location "North Europe" when migrating. Now I see that each bot was placed in its own resource group with the correct location "North Europe". However, inside these resource groups the actual Bot Channels Registration has location "global".

I cannot find any information about this. What does location "global" mean and how should I interpret the Bot Channels Registration being "global" while within a resource group in "North Europe"?

Any information much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Bot registrations contain information about the bot such as App ID/Password, channels, etc. They are not services that are deployed somewhere, that's why their location is global.

Answer (score 0):

From looking at a bot I have, I see this, too. If it's ok, I have a guess as to what it is.

I believe the bot itself is global in its location since it's just the code and settings for the bot. The App Service resource, however, is where the bot is deployed to on the web which does have a location.

Hopefully, you'll see the App Service in the North Europe location. :)

Comment: That's a good guess and hopefully that's the case. The App Service is in North Europe as you say. Would be nice to find some official explanation for the "global" location, but I haven't been able to...